# "services is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:tick:external-dns\" cannot list resource \"services\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, aws-alb, external-dns

I've been following the [walkthrough](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/walkthrough/echoserver/) to create an AWS ALB Ingress Controller for my app which is also deployed at an EKS cluster. 
 
Everything seems okay , similar answers with the walkthrough but when it comes to the setting up of an external DNS I  get the error :

```
kubectl logs -f $(kubectl get po | egrep -o 'external-dns[A-Za-z0-9-]+')
```

> time="2020-02-20T16:21:57Z" level=error msg="services is forbidden:
>   User \"system:serviceaccount:tick:external-dns\" cannot list resource
>   \"services\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"
>   time="2020-02-20T16:22:58Z" level=error msg="services is forbidden:
>   User \"system:serviceaccount:tick:external-dns\" cannot list resource
>   \"services\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"

every one minute .
I made sure that all the permissions are the needed ones so it should not be because of that.

I tried the solutions from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/issues/711) , but nothing helped and I couldn't find any other solutions.

What does this error practically means? What should I do to fix it?

UPDATE EDIT 
my `external-dns` configuration looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: external-dns
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::*my*account*id*:role/EKSRole
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: external-dns
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: ["extensions"]
  resources: ["ingresses"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["nodes"]
  verbs: ["list","watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: external-dns-viewer
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: external-dns
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: external-dns
  namespace: tick
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: external-dns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: external-dns
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: external-dns
      annotations:
        iam.amazonaws.com/role: arn:aws:iam::*my*account*id*:role/EKSRole
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: external-dns
      containers:
      - name: external-dns
        image: registry.opensource.zalan.do/teapot/external-dns:v0.5.9
        args:
        - --source=service
        - --source=ingress
        - --domain-filter=external-dns-test.my-org.com   #external-dns-test.my-org.com # will make ExternalDNS see only the hosted zones matching provided domain, omit to process all available hosted zones
        - --provider=aws
        - --policy=upsert-only # would prevent ExternalDNS from deleting any records, omit to enable full synchronization
        - --aws-zone-type=public # only look at public hosted zones (valid values are public, private or no value for both)
        - --registry=txt
        - --txt-owner-id=my-identifier
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65534
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error suggests that service account with name `external-dns` in `tick` namespace can't perform certain actions. In this case it is list services. To solve this you can apply the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: external-dns
  namespace: tick
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: external-dns-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: ["extensions"]
  resources: ["ingresses"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["nodes"]
  verbs: ["list","watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: external-dns-role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: external-dns-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: external-dns
  namespace: tick
```

Note, that first rule inside ClusterRole is granting correct permissions to list services in "" apiGroup, which is solving the error you have reported in your question.

Comment: Thanks , the only thing that was different was the field ```namespace``` which was ```default``` and changed it to ```tick``` . Now I need to figure out how to access my app through the service

Comment: @FloraBiletsiou I just updated my answer. In you ServiceAccount definition, you are also missing a namespace. If you don't specify it, the service account usually gets created in kube-system or default namespace.

Comment: the ServiceAccount was already at my ```tick``` namespace because I set it to be the default one, but I changed anyway

Comment: I am currently struggling the same issue, or at least the same error, despite the command: `kubectl auth can-i list service/poc-service --as system:serviceaccount:poc:poc-sa` returns `yes`. 
I tried assigning `cluster-admin` to `poc-sa` (with `kubectl create clusterrolebinding poc-admin --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount=poc:poc-sa`) and that seems to get rid of the error.
But that's a really bad solution, given the security risk involved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using  Amazon EKS with IAM Roles for Service Accounts therefore following [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md#manifest-for-clusters-with-rbac-enabled) should work. The walkthrough you were following, in the external DNS section Step [2](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/walkthrough/echoserver/#setup-external-dns-to-manage-dns-automatically) yaml file doesn't have your

```
annotations:
    # Substitute your account ID and IAM service role name below.
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID:role/IAM-SERVICE-ROLE-NAME
```

This error practically means your serviceaccount (external-dns) doesn't have permissions to access the kubernetes api server

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually added this part to my external-dns ServiceAccount configuration ,but since I am a beginner at AWS I am not sure if I have the correct **IAM-SERVICE-ROLE-NAME**.


my configuration looks like :

 
`annotations: eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn:arn:aws:iam::**myaccountid**:role/EKSRole ` 


I am not sure how to find the IAM-SERVICE-ROLE-NAME